# dropdown menu links not clickable

Tags: html, css, sass, focus

I'm creating a website for myself and was following a tutorial by codecourse, when I was done I noticed that the buttons were unclickable as when you clicked, the dropdown menu would disappear. Please help? Thanks in advance.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYN8FUiKfzA
Code [HTML]: `

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">

          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/cLogo.png" />
          <link rel="spreadsheets" href="styles/css/normalize.css">
          <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/global.css">     
        </head>
        <body>
          <header>
            <nav class="nav-main">
              <div class="logo">iTzPvPLyfe</div>
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-item">Home</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav-item">Apply</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-drop">dropdown</a>
              <div class="nav-content">
                <div class="nav-sub">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="skywars.html">Skywars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blitz SG</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>         
              <a href="#" class="nav-item">About</a>
            </nav>  
          </header>
    <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------- -->      
          <section class="content">
            <p>
             Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </section>
    <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------- -->      
          <footer>  
          </footer>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Code[SASS]:

```
.nav-main {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: $nav-background-color;
     height: 70px;
     color: $nav-foreground-color;

     .logo {
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 15px 30px;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 40px;
      }

      > ul {
      @extend %plainlist;
      float: left;
       > li {
          float: left;
        }
      }

    }

    .nav-item {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      color: $nav-foreground-color;
      text-decoration: none;

      &:hover {
          background: $nav-hover-color;
        }
    }

    .nav-drop {
      &:focus {
          background-color: $nav-hover-color;

          ~ .nav-content {
            max-height: 400px;
            @include transition(max-height, 0.4s, ease-in);
          }
      }
    }

    .nav-content {
      margin-left: 345px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 70px;  
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: $nav-background-color;
      max-height: 0;

      a {
        color: $nav-foreground-color;
        text-decoration: none;

        &:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
          }
      }
    }

    .nav-sub {
      padding: 20px;

      ul {
        @extend %plainlist;

        a {
          display: inline-block;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me. I don't think you included the mixins properly. Since you did not include them in the code snippet above, I went to the tutorial link and included them manually. Try checking to see if you have the mixins included in the sass file at the top like its shown in the tutorial. Make sure your filenames match, and your mixins match.

Your sass should convert to this css. Note, I adjusted the colors, and you should be able to take from here:

```
.nav-main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
}
.nav-main .logo {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-main > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}
.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: pink;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-item:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.nav-drop:focus {
  background-color: orange;
}
.nav-drop:focus ~ .nav-content {
  max-height: 400px;
  transition: max-height, 0.4s, ease-in;
}

.nav-content {
  margin-left: 345px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  max-height: 0;
}
.nav-content a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-sub {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-sub ul a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I did include my mixins where it is ~ .nav-content. Thanks for the help however.